# Implement Thread Android in my class?

Tags: java, android, xml, root

I would like to know how to implement a thread in this class to make it safe from the problems of ANR (Application Not Responding)

```
public class myClass {


    private static String LOG_TAG = Root.class.getName();

    public boolean isDeviceRooted() throws IOException {

        if (checkRootMethod1()){return true;}
        if (checkRootMethod2()){return true;}
        if (checkRootMethod3()){return true;}
        return false;

    }
    public boolean checkRootMethod1(){
        String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;

        if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkRootMethod2(){
        try {
            File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
            if (file.exists()) {
                return true;
            }
            else {

                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkRootMethod3() {
        if (new ExecShell().executeCommand(SHELL_CMD.check_su_binary) != null){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


        }
```

If for example this code is execute when i press a button, if i press many times this button, my app have an ANR.

Comment: you should probably start by finding out what part of the code is causing the ANR

Comment: Then learn how to use AsyncTask, as thats the easiest Android-standard way to perform a background action.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use a `Thread`, but an `AsyncTask`. Here's how:

Based on the following, figure out what you need for your app: `AsyncTask<TypeOfVarArgParams, ProgressValue, ResultValue>`

Some inspiration:

```
public class MyClass {
      //Something

      public MyClass() {
            new BackgroundTask().execute("Hello World");
      }
}

private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Prepare your background task. This will be executed before doInBackground
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Your main code goes here

            String iAmAString = "I have done something very heavy now...";
            return iAmAString;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Whatever should happen after the background task has completed goes here
      }



      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // In here, you can send updates to you UI thread, for example if you're downloading a very large file.
      }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but with my class how can I do?

Comment: @MariocciRossini: If you don't care about formalities, copy/paste your three verification methods into the class that extends `AsyncTask`, and put the body of your `isDeviceRouted` method inside the `doInBackground` method. Next up is figuring out how to return a `boolean` instead of a `String`. That you will learn best by researching how an `AsyncTask` works (no, really, do the research - you will need to use `AsyncTasks` a LOT most likely).

Comment: You're going to have to make some effort to try it yourself. If you run into difficulty update your question or post a new question detailing where you are stuck. SO is great for answering a basic question, but not a "write my code for me" resource.

Answer (score -4):

```
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            myClass rootChecker = new myClass();
            isRooted = rootChecker.isDeviceRooted();
        }
    };
```

Comment: With `AsyncTask` in Android, you shouldn't make your own `Thread`'s - this is all handled by `AsyncTask`, which, in fact, has been developed to enable developers to easily use threads.

Comment: A standard Thread can still be necessary for some long-running tasks, but would not be appropriate for something like this where the operation is run once and should be complete within a few seconds.